# flyway 3.1 Migration Checksum mismatch. Calculation of checksum is platform dependent

Tags: java, linux, database, flyway

I have a completely same project source and sql script in both windows and ubuntu client, development platform.
when I compile and try to deploy the project on my linux server, I receive this exception only for my linux version package.

Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Found differences between applied migrations and available migrations: Migration Checksum mismatch for migration V2__xxx_module.sql: DB=-1434535307, Classpath=-282428834
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1020)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:52)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:925)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:919)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1320)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:919)

it seems there is platform dependency in version 3.1 too.
I really need to work with both OS platform, so is there any way to fix that?

Update :

I saw that still many peoples have a same problem, so here is my way to fix the problem.

I just turned off the validation and waiting for flyway 4 that they said that this problem is fixed there.

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway(); 
...
flyway.setValidateOnMigrate(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is fixed in Flyway 4.0. See
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/253

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with Git: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/253

You can work around it by properly configuring CRLF handling in `.gitattributes` to have consistent line endings (LF) across all platforms by for example adding `* text eol=lf` and only adding exceptions for the binary formats.

Comment: `properly configuring` : can you add some detail please ?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1. use `flyway` version 4.0
2. use maven `Flyway.repair()`
3. Delete SQL file. Clean and rebuild. Create SQL file again.